ASP.NET Core 6 deployment with nginx on WSL - stuck / partial response for a bit long html document
I don't have any experience working with Linux. Now I tried to deploy ASP.NET Core 6 app on WSL with nginx. Working fine except one small issue. Response is not complete after sending 1500+ rows of html. Tbh response get stuck and only sometimes sending response. Then I disabled proxy buffering and caching from Nginx config and now seeing those 1500+ rows of incomplete html.

1500 lines roughly 70-80 KB.
Running on WSL so localhost.
Nginx version 18 and default config is there. I only created some config for test my applications. Taken from Microsoft official website for Asp.Net core deployment.
Accessing Kestrel on 5000 port working just fine. But Nginx not working for said case.
Nginx error log showing (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream AND (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream.
Kestrel does not have any error log, from DEBUG log it seems like its working and sending data. Application log showing accessing DB and sending data. Both Kestrel and Application log instantaneous.
I have googled and tried almost everything. But as I said I don't have any experience on Linux environment so it's possible that I have missed something. Or did something wrong.

Here is configuration from Microsoft official site. I have added log and some directives I am tinkering with.
http {
  map $http_connection $connection_upgrade {
    "~*Upgrade" $http_connection;
    default keep-alive;
  }

  server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   example.com *.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }
}

I mostly focused on Nginx's error log. So after googling I tried

Checking folder permission
Tinkering with some proxy config like proxy buffer, proxy cache etc.
Deploying project with specifying 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.


Please try to sets the keep-alive timeout to 5 mins. It's Default value is 130 seconds.

I'm also curious if you create a static 80kb cshtml file, can you run into this same problem?  If not then you need to give us more details on whether there are other tasks are running on this problematic page.

I have changed KeepAliveTimeout, RequestHeadersTimeout, MaxRequestBodySize, MinRequestBodyDataRate and MinResponseDataRate. Also copied dynamically generated cshtml content to a static cshtml file of same project. But problem still persists. And site works fine when I hit Kestrel directly, ie localhost:5000. Nginx error log is "Connection timed out - while reading upstream" and in Chrome sometimes no error and sometimes (failed)net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING. UI loads partially. Application log saying data calculation done instantly so I think problem is between Kestrel and Nginx.
